# Gap between toilet and a "glue" on the wall

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, plumbing-fixture, hanging

I don't know anything about plumbing, but recently I moved to a new apartment and noticed that there is a slight gap between the hanging toilet and some kind on a white glue on the wall. Check the photos below -

[image]

[image]

Should I be worried about it and call the plumber to fix it or it's just a cosmetic stuff?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The 'white glue' is just caulking to prevent moisture running behind.  Usually a simple remove/clean and replace job.  The reason the toilet seems to be separating/sinking down on wall might be cause of concern and should be investigated first.  Might just be a hanger needs tightening.  Landlord should check.

Comment: thank you for clarification!